# Connect to SAS Compute and execute .sas file with Paramiko and Sub Process in Python

Tags: python, sas, subprocess, paramiko

I have some code that connects SSH connects to the SAS compute server using Paramiko from a SAS Windows client machine and the attempts to execute a piece of .sas code that has been exported from an EG project:

```
import paramiko
import subprocess

COMP = "sas_comp_server_server"

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(COMP, username="", password="", allow_agent = False)

subprocess.call(['/data/sas/myserver/config/Lev1/SASApp/BatchServer/sasbatch.sh', '-sysin', '/data/myserver/myfolder/My SAS Job.sas', '-log', '/data/myserver/myfolder/My SAS Log.log'])
```

I know my sign on has worked as I have successfully completed an SFTP using it in another script. I know my UNIX command works as when I copy and paste into the terminal it runs my code successfully. However, when I use subprocess as per the above I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/myuser/Documents/Python 3 Scripts/SSH Server Logon.py", line 13, in <module>
    subprocess.call(['/data/sas/myserver/config/Lev1/SASApp/BatchServer/sasbatch.sh', '-sysin', '/data/myserver/myfolder/My SAS Job.sas', '-log', '/data/myserver/myfolder/My SAS Log.log'])
  File "C:\saswkapps\python3\lib\subprocess.py", line 304, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "C:\saswkapps\python3\lib\subprocess.py", line 756, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\saswkapps\python3\lib\subprocess.py", line 1155, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Can anyone please advise what is incorrect with the subprocess call?

Thanks

Comment: I am unsure why you believe this is a duplicate of your linked question. could you please elaborate?

Comment: It shows your how to correctly execute a command on the server. Or isn't that what you want? - Or do you want to execute a *local* `sasbatch.sh` with *remote* `My SAS Job.sas` script?

Comment: just talked your response through with a UNIX colleague (I'm python) and it makes more sense now. We have used the implementation in your linked question. thanks.